# What framework supports simple full-screen (i.e. no visible chrome) apps with basic text and polygons?

Tags: python, graphics, raspberry-pi, fullscreen

Trying to find the recommended (i.e. community-best-practices) framework for a Raspbian-based application to create a simple read-only (i.e. kiosk-like) user interface with only a few requirements:

1. It has to be able to run full-screen (i.e. no visible chrome, titles, clock, etc.)
2. It has to support the display of text strings using a non-raster font (i.e. TTF, ODF, etc.)
3. It has to be able to draw basic, primitive polygons via line segments and coordinates. (Displaying SVGs would be optimal, but I'm fine hand-drawing the line segments too.)
4. The entire screen/canvas/??? has to be 'rotatable' so any direction can be 'up'.

Some have directed me to [TKinter](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/), but I think that's a mistake as that appears to be for building application GUIs in Python (i.e. buttons, text boxes, list boxes, etc.)

Others have suggested PyGame but they seem a little overkill as that's a full-on gaming engine whereas I just need basic, non-animated display. Plus I haven't found any tutorials on how to make them full-screen with the rotation requirement addressed.

I've heard GTK/GTK# is also something worth looking into but that too seems overkill bringing in the entire Mono frameworks along for the ride (although I *do* love C#!)

I've searched for tutorials or similar using Google, but nothing seems to be a good fit. Getting to the point where I'm just going to 'grab one and run with it.', but I'd prefer to end up where the community considers best-practices.

Comment: FullPageOS + HTML/JS + https://github.com/amitdar/FullPageDashboard See also: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40631/setting-up-a-kiosk-with-chromium +

Comment: I disagree. I’m asking about an application and a framework. I happen to be using a raspberry pi, but I could use any Linux distribution, or in the case of python, several different platforms in general. That said, of course I respect your right to vote. Just wanted to offer you a different perspective.￼

Comment: Aaah. Gotcha! Makes sense.  I thought you downloaded it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Tkinter/tkinter because you 
need a graphical interface for your 
purpose.
It is part of the python standard 
library you don't have to install an 
additional library to use it.

1. It's able to run in full-screen.
2. You will need text boxes to display 
   your text strings. Just disable the 
   border then it will look like without 
   box or use the Canvas frame and display 
   your items and text.
3. Tkinter has a Canvas frame you can 
   draw all primitive polygons like arc, 
   line, polygon, rectangle and text as 
   well.
4. It's not clear for me what you mean 
   with rotatable I assume you have a 
   display like your tablet or mobile phone 
   so when you rotate the display it should 
   rotate your screen too? If so then you 
   need access to the tilt sensor. You can 
   in tkinter rotate your window or canvas 
   as well.

For me best GUI framework because easy, 
fast to use, for small and big projects, 
native and modern look, cross-
platform...

The only drawback: can not display 
images without third party library 
except bitmap.

I don't recommend PyGame it's overkill.
I don't recommend GTK because it's not 
easy as tkinter but you can use it and 
achieve the same result like with 
tkinter.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I can't use textboxes as there's too many sizes/variations of what we need to draw and the positions need to be pixel-specific.  I'm hoping for something like 'Render this string, using this font, with the baseline starting at x,y.  Maybe the canvas as you said?  As for #4, no, not for device rotation. I need to rotate the entire scene based on a parameter in a config file (e.g. 'Rotate the entire contents by 237 degrees'.

Comment: If you still think TKinter is the way to go, mind posting an example showing a really simple full-screen app? Just throw up a simple square with the word 'Square' written in any font under it. Then if possible, rotate the entire 'scene' by 45 degrees.  Just a simple jumping-off point. I'm just struggling with the setup itself. Once started I'll be fine.